# How to insert some words in the txt file

Tags: python-2.7

Now I want to add some words in a file, but I could only add some words in the end of file(.txt) via using f.open('xxx.txt','a')
If I use 'a+' mode, the words will take place the old one from beginning. I hope to insert some sentences in the first line without change the original ones.

```
# using python 2.7.12
  f = open('Bob.txt','w')
  f.write('How many roads must a man walk down'

  ' \nBefore they call him a man'

  ' \nHow many seas must a white dove sail'

  ' \nBefore she sleeps in the sand'

  ' \nHow many times must the cannon balls fly'

  " \nBefore they're forever banned"

  " \nThe answer my friend is blowing in the wind"

  " \nThe answer is blowing in the wind")
  f.close()
  # add spice to the song
  f1 = open('Bob.txt','a')
  f1.write("\n1962 by Warner Bros.inc.")
  f1.close()
  # print song
  f2 = open('Bob.txt','r')
  a = f2.read()
  print a
```

I hope to insert " Bob Dylan" in the first line, What code shall I add ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. You should read the file, modify it and rewrite it :

```
with open('./Bob.txt', 'w') as f :
    f.write('How many roads must a man walk down'

        ' \nBefore they call him a man'

        ' \nHow many seas must a white dove sail'

        ' \nBefore she sleeps in the sand'

        ' \nHow many times must the cannon balls fly'

        " \nBefore they're forever banned"

        " \nThe answer my friend is blowing in the wind"

        " \nThe answer is blowing in the wind")
# add spice to the song
file = []
with open('Bob.txt', 'r') as read_the_whole_thing_first:
    for line in read_the_whole_thing_first :
        file.append(line)
file = ["1962 by Warner Bros.inc.\n"] + file
with open('Bob.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in file:
        f.writelines(line)
with open('Bob.txt', 'r') as f2:
    a = f2.read()

print a
```

result :

```
1962 by Warner Bros.inc.
How many roads must a man walk down 
Before they call him a man 
How many seas must a white dove sail 
Before she sleeps in the sand 
How many times must the cannon balls fly 
Before they're forever banned 
The answer my friend is blowing in the wind 
The answer is blowing in the wind
```